# Stuck in this Algorithm of selection sort

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, swap, selection-sort

I simply can not find any error in my code for selection sort but the array comes out as unsorted. I need help. Also for some reason, the number '0' comes as output in each try even when the inputted array has no zero in it. I can't figure the error

> ```
> #include<stdio.h>
> int main(){
>   int size;
>   printf("Enter the number of elements of the array : ");
>   scanf("%d",&size);
>   int arr[size];
>   printf("Enter the elements :");
>   for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
>     scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
>   }
>   int min,temp,j,i;
>   for(i=0;i<size-1;i++){
>     min=i;
>     for(j=i+1;j<size;j++){
>       if(arr[j]<arr[min]){
>         min=j;
>       }
>     }
>     temp=arr[i];
>     arr[i]=arr[j];
>     arr[j]=temp;
>   }
>   printf("Sorted array is : \n");
>   for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
>     printf("%d\n",arr[i]);
>   }
>   return 0;
> }
> ```

Comment: Make swap into a function. Easier to read, less errors.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet that swaps two elements of the array

```
temp=arr[i];
arr[i]=arr[j];
arr[j]=temp;
```

is incorrect. You need to write

```
temp=arr[i];
arr[i]=arr[min];
arr[min]=temp;
```

Also it would be better to write

```
if ( i != min )
{
    temp=arr[i];
    arr[i]=arr[min];
    arr[min]=temp;
}
```

Pay attention to that you should declare variables in the minimal scope where they are used.

Your program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    size_t n;

    printf( "Enter the number of elements of the array: " );

    scanf( "%zu", &n );

    int arr[n];

    printf( "Enter the elements: " );
    for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < n; i++ )
    {
        scanf( "%d", arr + i );
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        size_t min = i;

        for ( size_t j = i + 1; j < n; j++ )
        {
            if ( arr[j] < arr[min] ) min = j;
        }

        if ( i != min )
        {
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[min];
            arr[min] = temp;
        }           
    }

    printf( "Sorted array is: " );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", arr[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter the number of elements of the array: 10
Enter the elements: 3 6 5 1 2 9 0 8 4 7
Sorted array is: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```